# Pi 3 B wireles access point ubuntu

Tags: wifi

I am trying to set up a Pi 3 B as a wireless access point. I am running Ubuntu 18.04 server for arm64. I followed the tutorial [here](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/setting-up-a-raspberry-pi-3-as-an-access-point/all), editing the required configuration files. However, during startup dnsmasq fails to start. Typing `systemctrl status dnsmasq` gives the following error:

```
failed to create listening socket for 192.168.5.1: Cannot assign requested address
```

Searching the web for this error did not give me any good hits. Also, despite editing my /etc/network/interfaces file and commenting out my ssid and passphrase, I can still connect to the internet on the pi. This probably has something to do with the netplan .yaml file still having them, although I don't know how relevant that might be: the tutorial had nothing about editing the .yaml file. Is there a workaround for this, or perhaps a tutorial specifically for Ubuntu for arm that I could follow?

Comment: It is futile trying to implement a Raspbian Stretch tutorial on Ubuntu which uses different network manager. If you had edited /etc/network/interfaces as suggested that would disable dhcpcd, so the tutorial is rather doubtful even on Raspbian.

Comment: I had a suspicion that would be the case, which is why I asked whether a Ubuntu arm tutorial is available anywhere. If not, documentation I could read would be helpful too.

Comment: There should be nothing ARM specific in implementing an Access Point - any Ubuntu Server tutorial should work. It depends on what networking software the server uses.

Comment: Ok, Ubuntu it is then. But I can't find a tutorial for setting up an access point on 18.04 server. Most use desktop, which has an out of the box option for making one.